# p:selectCheckboxMenu filterMatchMode not showing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this code:

```
<div class="p-col-12">
    <p:outputLabel for="tripType" value="Testing new title"/>
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="tripType"
                              value="#{analyticsController.selectedNewTripType}"
                              label="Cities"
                              filter="true"
                              filterMatchMode="in"
                              panelStyle="width:250px">
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{analyticsController.newTripType}" />
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu> </div>
```

And the controller is:

```
private String[] selectedNewTripType;
    private List<String> newTripType;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        newTripType = new ArrayList<String>();
        newTripType.add("Miami");
        newTripType.add("London");
        newTripType.add("Paris");
        newTripType.add("Istanbul");
        newTripType.add("Berlin");
        newTripType.add("Barcelona");
        newTripType.add("Rome");
        newTripType.add("Brasilia");
        newTripType.add("Amsterdam");
    }

    public String[] getSelectedNewTripType() {
        return selectedNewTripType;
    }

    public void setSelectedNewTripType(String[] selectedNewTripType) {
        this.selectedNewTripType = selectedNewTripType;
    }

    public List<String> getNewTripType() {
        return newTripType;
    }
```

I used like describe in the documentation https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml but this is the result:

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8REo.png)

Now I need somithing like this:

[This is I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqqiU.png)

And I don't know what happened, why doesn't it show even an error?
Could you help me please?
I am using PrimeFaces v8

Comment: There is some kind of CSS issue in your code. I have tested your code without the div and inside a form tag and there is no issue, the filter box is displayed properly

Comment: Thanks, in fact, the error was a class with display: none